# Update one column based on the first 3 letters of another

Tags: mysql

can someone help show me how to update one field in my table based on the first 3 letters in another field in MySql?

in my tblpeople I have a column called location, in it are various codes but where the code starts VOL- then I need to update the country column to USA, if it starts HOM- then update to Canada and finally HOME to united kingdom

Comment: Explaining along with some sample data would make things much easier

Comment: Do you have any sample code or attempts that you've made at this?  There are built in functions in mysql that would make this very easy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you started, but next time include what you have tried in your question.

```
update `tblpeople` set `country` = 'USA' where `location` like 'VOL-%';
```

Comment: Thanks jbird, first time here, will remember for the next time

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
UPDATE tblpeople 
SET    country = CASE 
                   WHEN location LIKE 'VOL-%' THEN 'USA' 
                   WHEN location LIKE 'HOM-%' THEN 'CANADA' 
                   WHEN location LIKE 'HOME%' THEN 'UNITED KINDOM' 
                   ELSE country 
                 END;
```